# How to copy a database from internal storage to external storage (suppose to be download folder)?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my application there is a database created by sqlite. I want to copy the database to download folder. I was using different way but not working in real device (it say access deny of the directory), may be it want rooted phone. Please help, I want to give a access so that user can get the database from the download folder.

Note that I'm using latest version android studio.

In below given DatabaseHelper class. In exportDB() method I want to implement this.

```
package com.tarikul.sqlitedatabase1;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Students.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_details";
    private static final String ID = "_id";
    private static final String NAME = "Name";
    private static final String AGE = "Age";
    private static final String GENDER = "Gender";
    private static final int  VERSION_NUMBER = 1;
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"("+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+NAME+" VARCHAR(155), "+AGE+" INTEGER, "+GENDER+" VARCHAR(15));";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
    private static final String SELECT_ALL_DATA = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    private Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION_NUMBER);
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            Toast.makeText(context,"OnCreate is called.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Exception: "+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(context,"onUpgrade is called.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Exception: "+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    public long insert(String name, String age, String gender)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(NAME,name);
        contentValues.put(AGE,age);
        contentValues.put(GENDER,gender);
        long rowId = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        return rowId;
    }

    public Cursor displayAllData(){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SELECT_ALL_DATA,null);
        return cursor;
    }

    public boolean updateData(String id, String name, String age, String gender)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(ID,id);
        contentValues.put(NAME,name);
        contentValues.put(AGE,age);
        contentValues.put(GENDER,gender);

        sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues,ID + " = ?",new String[]{id});
        return true;
    }

    public int deleteData(String id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return sqLiteDatabase.delete(TABLE_NAME,ID + " = ?", new String[]{id});
    }

    public void exportDB()
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In short you need to

## 1. get WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

- In the manifest have :- `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
- and if the build version is 23 or greater check/request it at runtime e.g. I use :-

  ```
  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
      ExternalStoragePermissions.verifyStoragePermissions(this);
  }
  ```

along with :-

```
class ExternalStoragePermissions {

    public int API_VERSION = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {

            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };

    public ExternalStoragePermissions() {}
    // Note call this method
    public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {

        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                activity,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if(permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            );
        }
    }
}
```

- Note the above should be done when the App first starts.

## 2. Prepare the database

You should close the database or at least checkpoint the database if it is using Write-Ahead logging (WAL). In WAL mode transactions (updates/inserts/deletions) are stored in the -wal and -shm files it is only when these transaction are committed (close or fully checkpointed) that part of the database is not held in these files so you need that data.

In journal mode, the changes made to the database are stored in the -journal file. These can be used to rollback changes made in the database *(roll back in WAL is removing the changes from the -wal and -shm files, so they never get applied to the database file)*.

The following method added to you **DatabaseHelper** class will checkpoint the database if need be :-

```
private void checkpointIfWALEnabled(Context context, String databaseName) {
    Cursor csr;
    int wal_busy = -99, wal_log = -99, wal_checkpointed = -99;
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(databaseName).getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode", null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        String mode = csr.getString(0);
        if (mode.toLowerCase().equals("wal")) {
            csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint", null);
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                wal_busy = csr.getInt(0);
                wal_log = csr.getInt(1);
                wal_checkpointed = csr.getInt(2);
            }
            csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE)", null);
            csr.getCount();
            csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint", null);
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                wal_busy = csr.getInt(0);
                wal_log = csr.getInt(1);
                wal_checkpointed = csr.getInt(2);
            }
        }
    }
    csr.close();
    db.close();
}
```

## 3. Do the Export

e.g. The following is and example of the core code you could use

```
        public void exportDB() {

            this.getWritableDatabase().close();
            try {
                String dbfilename = this.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
                File dbfile = new File(dbfilename);
                String backupfilename = (new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),null)).getPath() + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME + "-backup";
                checkpointIfWALEnabled(context,DATABASE_NAME);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbfile);
                OutputStream backup = new FileOutputStream(backupfilename);
                String methodname = new Object() {
                }.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[32768]; //32k buffer, may be changed
                int length;
                while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    backup.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                backup.flush();
                backup.close();
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

- Note the above code is extracted from working more complex code and has been adjusted slightly. It hasn't been tested or run so there may be some minor errors.
- I would suggest that just appending -backup will limit you to just one such file, you may wish to include a timestamp so that you can have multiple backups.